# In MongoDB how to return only part of array?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Consider collection "fruits", in which I have this document (I'm using Python's pymongo driver, btw):

```
{
    '_id'       : 'lemons',
    'weight'    : 58,
    'shape'     : 'oval',
    'countries' : ['Mexico', 'Turkey', 'Argentina', 'SAfrica', 'US']
}
```

Now, if I want to get only the 'countries' field, this query works just fine:

```
In [1]: find_one('lemons', { 'countries' : 1, '_id' : 0 })
Out[1]: {u'countries': [u'Mexico', u'Turkey', u'Argentina', u'SAfrica', u'US']}
```

But it turns out that what I really need is just list of few top-countries, not all of them, so I'm using "$slice" instead of plain True/1:

```
In [239]: c.find_one('lemons', { 'countries' : { '$slice' : [0, 3] }, '_id' : 0 })
Out[239]: 
{u'countries': [u'Mexico', u'Turkey', u'Argentina'],
 u'shape': u'oval',
 u'weight': 58}
```

Well, number of countries has shrinked, but now it gives me whole lot of other unrelated information!

**Q:** Is there any way to show only those fields that I have asked for? Additionally listing '_id' as exception is fine, because this field is always presented, but I can't be sure about other fields, since MongoDB is scheme-less and I intend to use this feature to add additional fields if needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried adding another inclusion projection? I think you may be able to add something trivial like foo:1 (that is not a real field) and it should work.

Like so:

```
{ 'countries' : { '$slice' : [0, 3] }, '_id' : 0, foo : 1 }
```

If it doesn't work I suggest filing a bug with mongo. They are actually very good about responding to bugs.

Comment: Wow, that seems to work! what made you think of adding another "dummy" field?

Comment: I've done a lot with mongo and there always seems to be a workaround to making their code work as expected =p

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome (if unexpected) solution.

Comment: I can't believe there isn't a more official solution to this...? I asked myself the same question as OP the moment I read about $slice. Which was around two seconds after reading about limiting fields, since those two articles are *[right next to each other](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)*...

Comment: Great answer.  It makes sense, given Mongo semantics.  There is no schema for a document, so the query has to accommodate arbitrary document contents.  This projection tells it to project 'foo' and a slice of 'countries', and leave everything else out.  There's no 'foo', so it's left out of the result, and we're left with just the sliced 'countries'.  Beautiful.

Comment: Holyshit, I'm facing the same problem, isn't this a bug of pymongo? I can't believe this bug still exists today.

Comment: wow, that's neat thx a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

That's strange because that's not the behavior when running in the mongo console.

Have you tried putting `'lemons'` in curly braces so it's valid JSON syntax?

```
find_one({'_id':'lemons'}, { 'countries' : 1, '_id' : 0 })
```

It looks to me like it's applying your $slice projection to all of the fields, so it could be some weird syntax issue with the pymongo driver

Comment: `find_one({'_id' : 'lemons'}, { 'countries' : {'$slice' : [0,3] }, '_id' : 0 })` gives the same result as mentioned, I'll test how it works in mongo shell.

Comment: Mongo shell gives me the same result as well, unfortunately. I'm running 2.2.3 version of MongoDB, if that matters.

Comment: Looks like this is by design and is an known issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3378. You'd have to explitly suppress all other fields, but as you've explained you won't necessarily know them all if your adding to a dynamic schema

Comment: Ok, I guess than I better change `_id: 0` to `_id: 1`, this way MongoDB returns only sliced array plus id field, which at least is predictable.