# How do we limit the index for retrieved array document in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb

lets take a sample collection with dummy data

```
{
_id:*******
value:[{id:'*',value:'12'},{id:'*',value:'12'},{id:'*',value:'12'},{id:'*',value:'12'}...]

}
```

I found that data can be pushed in array by $push but how will i be able to get the array in mongoDb with limited index, i.e if i want the value from only zero index to 20 not all at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MongoDB how to return only part of array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797379/in-mongodb-how-to-return-only-part-of-array)

Comment: Use [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) in mongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.coll.find({}, {'value':{$slice: 20}});
```