# Select last value of array in sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "prices" : { 
        "100" : [
                5.67,
                .
                .
                1.7,    
            ], 
        "101" : [
                4.67,
                .
                .
                1.4,  
    }, 
    "v" : 2 
}
```

We need to get the last value from each of the fields "100" and "101", e.g 1.7 & 1.4, using mongodb v3.0.2. Currently we are loading the whole document and then getting the required values in the application. It has become quite a bottleneck as each document may be ~1MB, which for 100s of documents is adding up.

We are hoping there is a suitable feature of mongodb that will allow us to just retrieve the data we need from the document, possibly as a separate call for each price field, i.e one call for the price "100" key and second call for the price "101" key.

We have experimented using the $slice operator but this unfortunately cannot be used with exclusion fields, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3378.

We have also seen the following post:
[How to combine both $slice and select returned keys operation in function update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670073/how-to-combine-both-slice-and-select-returned-keys-operation-in-function-update)

Which almost works, but the return value from the query:

```
db.account_articles.find({"_id" : ObjectId("1")}, { "prices.100" : { $slice: -1 }, "_id" : 1 })
```

is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "prices" : { 
        "100" : [
                1.7    
            ], 
        "101" : [
                4.67,
                .
                .
                1.4,  
    }
}
```

i.e. it's 90% of the way there, we just need to be able to exclude the "101" field.

Are we missing something or is this not possible in monogodb?

Comment: The problem here is that "prices" is just an object with keys. If your "100" and "101" were just properties of the array as in `{ "prices": [{ "type": "100", "value": 1.7 },{ "type": "101", "value": 4.67 }] }` then at least the upcoming `$filter` and `$slice` operators of the aggregation framework as available in the development branch would be able to do the job. Right now, you need mapReduce, or do it on the client once the result is retrieved. Or actually you could still do it with the aggregation framework "now", but it's just not as great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the aggregation framework to do this, I think you really should change the stucture, but working with what you have:

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
       { "$match": { "prices.100": { "$exists": true } }},
       { "$unwind": "$prices.100" },
       { "$group": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "price": { "$last": "$prices.100" }
       }},
       { "$project": { "_id": 0, "prices.100": "$price" } }
     ]
)
```

In future releases you will be able to just use the new `$slice` operator:

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "prices.100": { "$exists": true } } },
        { "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "prices.100": { "$slice": ["$prices.100",-1] }
        }}
    ]
)
```

In fact you can do "both" fields at the same time:

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "prices.100": { "$exists": true } } },
        { "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "prices.100": { "$slice": ["$prices.100",-1] },
            "prices.101": { "$slice": ["$prices.100",-1] }
        }}
    ]
)
```

And that is a lot better than processing with [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) to get the last element of the array when [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is applied to get the data back.

It basically has the same performance as a regular query in the newer form. In the present form, it's going to be slower.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Two questions, 1 - Over what sort of timescale might the new $slice operator available. 2 - I'm not familiar with the aggregate operation. Where in your first example would I specify the document id, e.g. {"_id" : ObjectId("1")}

Comment: @MarcF  Well release cycles are genrally "targeted" now at 6 months, but I notice the repo is still actively "packing things in", which in a way is a good thing. Not aware of any firm dates as yet. As for (2) then you put in in the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline, which is really just a "query" with standard operators.

Comment: Excellent, I have this working. Many kind thanks for the v.fast response. I'll look forward to the updated release.

Comment: One final question, is there an extension to the aggregation pipeline that allows me to get the last N elements if they exist, rather than only $last?

Comment: Yes. `$slice` as already mentioned. You "can" do it with the current operators ( just as you could get both "100" and "101" as well).  But as you can imagine ( maybe not yet ) it's a horrible iterative process of repeating the steps shown here and marking off the "seen" values in the array. I know there is at least one answer sitting around on StackOverflow that shows how to do this, and also recommends against doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this simple and lot easier solution.

[Return latest record from subdocument in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617676/return-latest-record-from-subdocument-in-mongodb/50382062#50382062)

just get the last index of your array item and you are done.