# MongoDB allow multiple join and left dates

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I currently have a query, thanks to the community here on StackOverflow.

Users can have one-on-one conversations, as well as group chats with up to 25 people. The idea behind my database is to keep a conversations document and a messages document which are linked to each other using the _id from the conversation. This is my conversations document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "n" : "Example Group Chat",
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "admin",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "4",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "l" : 1581863346,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "5",
            "j" : 1580581922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "9",
            "j" : 1580593922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "3",
            "j" : 1580594920,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "8",
            "j" : 1580594999,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e39d5d740713a43aeef5b26"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "2",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see a group chat (first) and a one-on-one chat (second). Group chats can have names (n), one-on-one chats not. Every conversation has an array of members, which stores the userID (uID), the join date (j), the left date (l), an invited by userID field (i), a role field (r) and an active field (a). I probably won't need the "active" field, as I have a join/left timestamp, but still. I'll probably delete it later, so that field probably won't be included.

Next, I have my `messages` document as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4917bca59ce44ef2770086"),
    "c_ID" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "msg" : "Whats good?",
    "fromID" : "1",
    "__v" : 0,
    "t" : 1582369525,
    "d" : {
        "4" : 1582369525
    },
    "r" : {
        "4" : 1582369525
    }
}
```

This holds the message itself (msg), the user who sent it (fromID), the timestamp in UNIX Epoch (t) and subcollections of deliveries (d) and reads (r) and of course the conversation ObjectID (c_ID).

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "members.uID": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      user: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$members",
              as: "member",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$member.uID",
                  "4"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "messages",
      let: {
        user: "$user",
        conversatoinId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$c_ID",
                    "$$conversatoinId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $lt: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$user.l",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$user.j"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: true,
                    else: {
                      $lt: [
                        "$t",
                        "$$user.l"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    "$t",
                    "$$user.j"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },

        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "t": -1
          },

        }
      ],
      as: "messages"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      lastMessage: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$messages",
          0
        ]
      },
      n: 1,
      members: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "lastMessage.t": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      members: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$members",
          as: "member",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$$member.uID",
                  "4"
                ]
              },
              {
                $or: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$member.l",
                      undefined
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lt: [
                      "$$member.l",
                      "$$member.j"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      memberCount: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$members",
            as: "member",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$$member.uID",
                    "4"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $or: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$member.l",
                        undefined
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lt: [
                        "$$member.l",
                        "$$member.j"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      n: 1,
      lastMessage: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      lastMessage: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  }
])
```

Now, the issue:

Imagine there is a group chat with 20 members. The name of the chat is "Funky Fridays". userID 4 joins that group chat (I set the `j` (join) field to `1582475543` (timestamp), participates for twee weeks and then leaves (I set the `l` (left) field to `1583685143` (timestamp). This will all work fine. However, how can I add userID 4 again to the same group chat 1 week later (timestamp `1584289943`) and make sure userID 4 can see the lastMessage IF it is either between the first time he joined/left OR if it's posted after he joined again?**

I would like to be able to add the same user more than once to the members array, but with different `j` (and `l`) fields, and then query the lastMessage to be between one of them, which would allow for what I want to do as described above.

So basically I would like to have my `conversations` document as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "n" : "Example Group Chat",
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "admin",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "4",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "l" : 1581863346,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "5",
            "j" : 1580581922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "9",
            "j" : 1580593922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "3",
            "j" : 1580594920,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "8",
            "j" : 1580594999,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        },
        {
            "uID" : "4",
            "j" : 1581982392,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 0
        }, 
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e39d5d740713a43aeef5b26"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "2",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

So userID 4 has joined, participated in the chat, left, and later joined again. I want him to be able to see the chat in the overview of all his conversations.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

**EDIT: Based on Joe's suggestion, I'd like to go with something like below. Any opinions? I'm wondering how I would use the structure below to show only the latest message before the last leave timestamp (`1581963346`), not any message posted after those. Or if there are multiple join/leave dates, I'd like to show the last matching message. Later on, I'd use those dates to show the messages the user is allowed to see. So only those when he was present in the group chat.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "n" : "Example Group Chat",
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "admin",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "4",
            "events" : [
                { type: "join", date: 1581863346 },
                { type: "leave", date: 1581963346 }
            ],
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "5",
            "j" : 1580581922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "9",
            "j" : 1580593922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "3",
            "j" : 1580594920,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT 2: My main source of concern is querying between the date someone joined a group and the date someone left a group. I'll give an example below.**

Conversation X

- 10:00 AM: Person A joins the conversation and can't see any messages yet
- 10:05 AM: Person B posts a message
- 10:07 AM: Person C posts a message
- 10:10 AM: Person A posts a message
- 10:12 AM: Person B posts a message
- 10:15 AM: Person A leaves the conversation
- 10:20 AM: Person C posts a message

**At this point, I want person A to be able to see conversation X still in his overview, with the message from person B (10:12 AM) as the last message. When I go into the conversation, I want all messages between 10:00 AM and 10:15 AM to be shown to person A. So only the last message from person C (10:20 AM) should not be shown.**

- 10:30 AM: Person B posts a message
- 10:32 AM: Person A joins the conversation again
- 10:35 AM: Person C posts a message
- 10:37 AM: Person A posts a message
- 10:38 AM: Person C posts a message

**At this point, I want person A to see the latest message from person C in his overview. In the conversation itself, I want to show the messages between 10:00 AM and 10:15 AM, as well as the ones between 10:32 AM and 10:38 AM.**

***I am merely wondering how I can structure my data AND how to query for the overview (based on my query above) to achieve this. I'll take care of the conversations and showing all relevant messages for a certain user later.***

Comment: It occurred to me while reading this post I was confusing an RDBMS concept called LEFT OUTER JOIN with your field names `left` and `join`.  For clarity sake you may want to consider changing the field names (just for this post).

Comment: This might be simpler if you actually used the "active" bit, i.e. let `j` and `l` be arrays, when a user joins, push a new date to `j` and set `a` to 1, when they leave push a new date to `l` and set `a` to 0, then the query  would simply need to match {a:1} to see what to include.

Comment: @Joe what you are describing is exactly what I was thinking when adding the active field. However, I’m not sure if I want join/left timestamps to be in arrays, because I’d like to keep the relationship between them at all times. Otherwise it’d be hard to match multiple periods, no? Any example or idea on how to set up that query?

Comment: The best way to store it will really depend on how you intend to use the data.  Instead of storing them in separate fields, store an array of events like `[{type:"join",date:ISODate()},{type:"leave",date:ISODate()},{type:"join",date:ISODate()}]`.  With the array in order by date, the last event will indicate the current state, and corresponding events will be adjacent in the array.  This is just one of many possibilities.

Comment: @Joe I agree. I've updated my question with something I'd use, based on your suggestion. Any idea on how I could query this or adopt my query I'm currently using to match what I need?

Comment: With the new information about how you want to query, it might actually work better with an array of membership times like `[{join: 1581863346, leave: 1581963347},{join: 1581963348}]`, then you could test if a message occurred during a time the user was a member with something like `{events:{$elemMatch:{join:{$lte:msgtime},{leave:{$gte:msgtime}}}}`

Comment: @Joe Hm, that seems reasonable. I've added a second edit to illustrate my main paint of concern. Would the above handle all of this well?

Comment: Also, where would I add the `elemMatch` operator? I've tried a bunch of things just now, but I don't get the expected results.

Comment: Any idea? Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

In the `$lookup` stage, pull in messages matching conversation id and across multiple join and leave timelines followed by `$sort` descending and `$limit` to pick the overview message.

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"members.uID":"4"}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"messages",
    "let":{
      "members":{
         "$filter":{
          "input":"$members",
         "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.uID","4"]}
         }
       },
      "conversation_id":"$_id"
    },
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{
        "$expr":{
          "$and":[
            {"$eq":["$c_ID","$$conversation_id"]},
            {"$ne":["$fromID","4"]},
            {"$gt":[
              {"$size":{
                "$filter":{
                  "input":"$$members",
                  "cond":{
                    "$cond":[
                      {"$gt":["$$this.l",null]},
                      {"$and":[
                        {"$gte":["$t","$$this.j"]},
                        {"$lte":["$t","$$this.l"]}
                      ]},
                      {"$gte":["$t","$$this.j"]}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }},
              0
            ]}
          ]
        }
      }},
      {"$sort":{"t":-1}},
      {"$limit":1}
    ],
    "as":"overviewMessage"
  }}
])
```

If you like to use

```
events:[{ "join": 1581863346, "left": 1581863348},{ "join": 1581863349, "left": 1581863355}...]
```

You can use the following query

```
db.conversations.aggregate(
[
  {"$match":{"members.uID":"4"}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"messages",
    "let":{
      "member":{
        "$arrayElemAt":[
          {
           "$filter":{
            "input":"$members",
           "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.uID","4"]}
           }
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      "conversation_id":"$_id"
    },
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{
        "$expr":{
          "$and":[
            {"$eq":["$c_ID","$$conversation_id"]},
            {"$ne":["$fromID","4"]},
            {"$gt":[
              {"$size":{
                "$filter":{
                  "input":"$$member.events",
                  "cond":{
                    "$cond":[
                      {"$gt":["$$this.left",null]},
                      {"$and":[
                        {"$gte":["$t","$$this.join"]},
                        {"$lte":["$t","$$this.left"]}
                      ]},
                      {"$gte":["$t","$$this.join"]}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }},
              0
            ]}
          ]
        }
      }},
      {"$sort":{"t":-1}},
      {"$limit":1}
    ],
    "as":"overviewMessage"
  }}
])
```

Comment: This seems to not hold into account the events in my db. Take a look at the last structure, where I am using an array of events (join/leave) to allow for multiple join/leave dates. That’s kind of the most important thing for me now. If you have suggestions on how to structure my database better, feel free to suggest. I want to be able to join/leave as many times as I want, and retrieve the last message I’m allowed to see (so it should be sent between join/leave timestamps). Any idea?

Comment: Could you try with original structure where you add a new entry ?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure if my current way to hold the join & leave dates (under “events”) is going to work. I’m not entirely sure on how to make sure I can query between two relevant join/leave dates. However, every leave date should follow a join date per definition. But if there were a way to make sure they are always “grouped”, I’d like to go with that approach.

Comment: Hmm, @SagarVeeram I’ll take a look. So every time someone joins, I’d need to add a new entry under members? Can I then retrieve all members easily, without duplicate content? I’d also like to retrieve the number of active members, so the ones with no leave date I suppose? Let me take a look.

Comment: Just a thought. For the updated structure it will make more sense to update the entry as oppose to adding. So something like `events:[{ "join": 1581863346, "left": 1581863348},{ "join": 1581863349, "left": 1581863355}...]` if you like to group them.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I just need a history of the timestamps where someone was active in the chat. So the events array could contain unlimited amounts of timestamps.

Comment: Updated. The query I've searches across all the history of user's timestamp to find the last message. If it is relevant and you have many values in history one way to make the query efficient is to check if there were any messages sent for timestamp when he leaves and add that to the document with leave timestamp like `events:[{ "join": 1581863346, "left": 1581863348, "hasMessages": true},{ "join": 1581863349}...]`. This way you have to search in atmost two in history to find the last message. I would like you to try first with what we have and we can add this enchancement if we need.

Comment: Cheers! That looks amazing. I’ll try both options. One advantage I see over the different documents for join/leaves, is I can add more different values like “is admin” or “invited by”, so I might go with your first suggestion if that reveals to have no other disadvantages. But I could easily add that to the events as well.

Comment: First solution seems to work. However, I'd like to try the array of events, but got following error: "errmsg" : "Use of undefined variable: members"

Comment: Yeah my mistake. Updated and added few other checks to both queries. Try now. Thanks

Comment: Still got the following error: "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null" - I'm however also looking into the fix as we speak. We should almost be there I figure.

Comment: Stupid, my mistake. I had gone for "e" instead of "events". Works now! I'm having lunch in a minute, but will experiment with different messages to see if they are shown or not. Seems to work at first sight, so let me thank you a million times already. I'll let you know in a minute if all works according to my needs. What did you mean exactly with the "hasMessages" parameter? Adding this would allow us to query over only the last relevant "events" object to find the last message, as apposed to all messages being checked right now?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes that is correct. We can skip "events" instances where you already know there were no messages ("hasMessages") sent between join and leave time. In our current query we are looking for messages between _all_ join/leave times and sorting the messages time desc and limiting it to 1.  With "hasMessages" we can narrow it down to atmost _two_ "events" instances, one with latest "hasMessages" is true or/and not present (as in case for active events row).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you filter messages not equal to fromID = userID? I'd like to show messages I've sent myself to show as well, as you see on Messenger and such (I'll append "You: " to those messages), so I would just remove it. But wondering if there is a special reason why this is in there?

Comment: No, I just assume you didn't want to show your own message. You can remove the check. Thanks

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted. So this is the answer to my question and I'll reward you the bounty. If you'd like, feel free to optimize according to your suggestion with the hasMessages parameter, but as that was not part of the original question: don't feel obliged. There are a couple of other optimizations I have in mind, but I'll figure those out on my own. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more issue I am facing, working with those subdocuments under "events", I want to only show members who are still in the conversation. So I want to retrieve the last events array/subdocument, sorted by the join date to retrieve the last one, and check if there is no "left" date (meaning the person is still in the conversation). I've checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115002/select-last-value-of-array-in-sub-document but I can't get it to work. How could I do this?

Comment: You're welcome - Please try `db.conversations.aggregate([
 {"$project":{"active":{
   "$filter":{
     "input":"$members",
     "cond":{"$gt":[
         {"$size":{
           "$filter":{
             "input":"$$this.events",
             "cond":{
               "$lte":["$$this.left",null]
             }
           }
         }},
         0
       ]}
   }
 }}}
])`

Comment: Awesome. One more thing I noticed: it's not sorted based on the timestamp (t), but rather the created_at date. Any chance I can sort it on t? I've tried sort:{t:1} and sort:{t:-1} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I want to introduce “pagination” where I load 10 conversations at a time, thus setting the timestamp of the last retrieved conversation. Then, for the second request, I want to retrieve the 11-20th message after this timestamp and after the last retrieved (#10 of request 1) conversation ID to avoid double results. Is this possible in this query or should I open a new question for this?

Comment: Please go ahead and ask new question. Thank you.